# Recursive Tree passing additional integer

Tags: haskell, tree

I need this for my homework, I'm pretty much done with my solution but I have one last subproblem left that I can't figure out how to solve..

```
type Notes = [(Int,Int,Int,Int)]
data Tree = Leaf Notes | Node Notes [Tree]]
    deriving(Eq,Show)

identity :: Tree -> Tree
identity (Leaf mi   ) = Leaf (transformNote mi 2)
identity (Node mi xs) = Node (transformNote mi 2) (map identity xs)
```

So what I'm trying to achieve with this function is:
take a tree, map the tree to itself but change the argument mi to (transformNote mi 2).

This code works and executes everything as expected, but what I actually need is a function

```
identity :: Tree -> Int -> Tree
```

so that my function turns into something like this:

```
identity :: Tree -> Int -> Tree
identity (Leaf mi   ) amount = Leaf (transformNote mi amount)
identity (Node mi xs) amount = Node (transformNote mi amount) (map identity xs amount)
```

This won't work since

```
(map identity xs amount) throws errors.
```

I tried so many ways to fix this, throw the amount variable around the terms but nothing seems to work. I can't make sense of why none of my solutions work.

Can anyone help? Thx

Comment: What does "throws errors" mean? You should look more closely at those error messages as they tell you exactly what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well *all* subtrees `s`, need to be replaced with an `identity s amount`. That means we can write a *lambda expression* `\s -> identity s amount` that thus will convert a *single* subtree. We can then use that expression in a `map`:

```
identity :: Tree -> Int -> Tree
identity (Leaf mi   ) amount = Leaf (transformNote mi amount)
identity (Node mi xs) amount = Node nmi (map (\s -> identity s amount) xs)
    where nmi = transformNote mi amount
```

The `where` clause is here used only to make the code fit on the available page width.

But this is rather ugly. We can use [**`flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip) that flips the two arguments. In that case, we can write it as:

```
identity :: Tree -> Int -> Tree
identity (Leaf mi   ) amount = Leaf (transformNote mi amount)
identity (Node mi xs) amount = Node nmi (map (flip identity amount) xs)
    where nmi = transformNote mi amount
```

Because it frequently introduces ugly expression, this is one of the reasons why in Haskell usually the parameters themselves are flipped:

```
-- flipped version
identity2 :: Int -> Tree -> Tree
identity2 amount (Leaf mi   ) = Leaf (transformNote mi amount)
identity2 amount (Node mi xs) = Node nmi (map (identity2 amount) xs)
    where nmi = transformNote mi amount
```

Comment: Im trying to understand this right now. Thanks so far!

Comment: I went for the first solution because I don't really understand the other 2. First should be fine though and is the closest to how I would've solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is actually easier if you generalize. Make `Tree` parameterized so that it's an instance of `Functor`:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node a [Tree a] deriving (Eq,Show)

instance Functor Tree where
  fmap f (Leaf x) = Leaf (f x)
  fmap f (Node x xs) = Node (f x) (fmap (fmap f) xs)
```

Now you can transform the elements of a `Tree` however you see fit:

```
identity :: Tree Notes -> Int -> Tree Notes
identity t amount = fmap (\n -> transformNote n amount) t
```

By the way, `identity` is a bad name for a function since by mathematical (and Haskell) convention, the identity function is

```
id :: a -> a
id x = x
```

That is, the function that simply returns its argument.

Comment: This is elegant, but I fear that the OP has to learn the basics before being able to understand functors. (+1)